# Почему нет кнопки обновить у приложения в Google Play

Tags: android, android-sdk

Залили новую версию приложения, старую деактивировали. Но при этом кнопка обновить в приложении не появилась. Кто с таким сталкивался? С чем это может быть связано? Прошло уже более 5 часов после публикации.

Comment: Номер версии на странице приложения поменялся?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja да, на странице версия поменялась, но кнопка обновиться не появилась, при этом на устройстве старая версия. Однако если удалить старую версию и зайти скачать, то приложение будет обновлено. Но Это плохое решение.... Есть идеи? (ПС кстати мы изменили целевой пакет разработчика с 23 до 19, это могло повлиять??)

Comment: minSdk не меняли? Единственное, что приходит в голову, на телефоне была старая версия с другой подписью, debug например.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja minSdk не меняли, только целевой пакет разработчика понизили для поддержки более старых телефонов.

Comment: для поддержки старых телефонов `minSdkVersion` снижают. `targetSdkVersion` устанавливает уровень API для компилятора, на что ругаться, на что нет.

Comment: targetSdkVersion не влияет на обновления, если packageName и сертификат подписи совпадают, и приложение все еще доступно для этого девайса (по minSdkVersion), то будет предложено обновиться.

Comment: На устройстве, в диспетчере приложений, найдите стандартное приложение Play Маркет, остановите его, очистите его КЭШ и запустите заново.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, вернули targetSdk к прежднему значению 23, выпустили, но до сих пор кнопки обновить нет, только открыть, все решается удалением и установкой по-новой, но для текущих пользователей это ад... Какие есть идеи проверки в чем трабла ? ПС написали в поддержку гугла, но они кроме почистить кеш, который не помогает ничем не смогли пока помочь... очень нужна помощь

Comment: А почему вы решили что у всех пользователей так?

Comment: У меня есть порядка 4-5 устройств, где нет возможности обновить, а еще по статистики установка была лишь 1 раз (это наверное, то, что сам и тестировал)